# Regex is not matching properly, trying to match file name excluding extensions

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^(file.+)\.pdf$/g
```

This should be capturing the file names except the extension. 
But that is not happen in my case.

[image]

Got this solution from this site
https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups

Comment: there is a full match and group. have a look:  https://regex101.com/r/HgqDji/1

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` as what you're looking for is not always at the start and at the end of string (at the same time or otherwise).

Comment: You're getting *no* matches because your regex requires input that begins with `file` (but your input begins with `Capture`). If you add a multiline `m` flag (see the "Flags" menu on regexr.com) then the regex will run against each line individually instead of the whole input at once.

Comment: As for why it still captures the extension when you do that, see the duplicate, or use a lookahead: `/^file.+(?=.pdf$)/`

Comment: @Walk solved my issue. You can write this as an answer.

Comment: I can't as this post is already marked as duplicate, glad I could help :)

Comment: "file_record_transcript.pdf file_07241999.pdf testfile_fake.pdf.tmp ".match(/(file.+)\.pdf/g)      -------     this should get me array of filenames in the console. But that's not happening :(

Comment: Check duplicate for more info about matching groups. However your regular expression in this case should be "\b(file[^\s]+)\.pdf\b" (notice boundary tags and NOT whitespace inside filename). Check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzbyBw